# Graph API SharePoint site search not working with App Permissions

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get a list of my (top-level) SharePoint sites.

This works with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*`

The problem is when I use `Application Permissions` which doesn't work. According to [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/site_search) I only need the following permissions:

> Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

I think there's a bug with the search, I always back an empty array.

But I can literally do everything else once I know my `site-id` with the same access token e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}`

So:

- How can I get search to work with App permissions?
- or is there another way to get a list of my sites?

**Update:**

In case it matters, we registered using Application Registration Portal ([apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)).

So basically followed these steps for app permissions: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/auth_v2_service.md

**Update 2:**
I've contacted ms devchat and the MS dev's tenant works fine with my app id (ruling out that) and so we tried my tenant with his app id and it also didn't want to work. He finally came to the conclusion it must be a bug with "Sites.FullControl.All" permission (as it's still in preview).

Temporarily I've resorted to SharePoint Online API just to enumerate sites which means I have to manage 2 tokens and generate and drag along a cert to make it work. This is really not great but the only way I can enumerate sites...

Here's an expired access token (requested in comments):

```
  eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEWDhHQ2k2SnM2U0s4MlRzRDJQYjdyQlluNjBQM3BhY1Mta1k5QVBiUlJuNEI2TVhrUlE5c1VfdzdfVHQtVHlGTnlXcEdJd0VxLVI0aGtaMmtqaDNFRllrNkItTk9CNk9OaHZYSlNrSFRjdFNBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiVGlvR3l3d2xodmRGYlhaODEzV3BQYXk5QWxVIiwia2lkIjoiVGlvR3l3d2xodmRGYlhaODEzV3BQYXk5QWxVIn0.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.kun-neHPcYAOBFWokBKLLMr5iSjQMEz14xfQMtKbxKUu_1kNZeV7EuSINSRRYwBqSxy0Sts1MFG4ywBLQQ1jdG-cJnjEveReJZxn1fgKRK6D0Y3gZwmj0LgdFvDR9QhpDMrEsfQ7Tl_JYwXsqPTPcDPoI3XnHqy71vS3Z242OwagvTPC2JTayeonje6yK6UGTRa1U8YEZYmUcxN-GJ_zZd6YjMD5UgT_CATTlvHHvqs2y-KfZ-pg6VZR75DfYHrWHDOnZPIHcf7IxfpQBMAFE077OapV2KkbFxEFaFF0Q_zJYdIAXm1iyT9nCikq_ZQ9zgqQqD3NKnYwORWsB83jog
```

Comment: This sounds like either a bug in the API (or the docs). I'll dig around and see if I can confirm which it is. One aside, you shouldn't need both of those scopes. The `Sites.ReadWrite.All` scope is a superset of `Sites.Read.All`.

Comment: Thanks Marc, just to confirm, we registered our application using http://apps.dev.microsoft.com and not via App Registration in Azure AD. I updated the question accordingly and added the link we followed to get app permissions going.

Comment: Have you gone through the Admin Consent process? Also, could you add an example of the token you're getting back?

Comment: Yes I've gone through Admin consent (all other api's are working). With help of devchat I've tried a few more things see updated question.

Comment: While it's possible there is an issue with `sites.fullcontrol.all`, I don't see how this would impact this endpoint since it doesn't apply to it. If you remove that scope does it suddenly start working?

Comment: Sorry Marc, I meant `site.readwrite.all` not fullcontrol. I removed all scopes except  `site.readwrite.all` and still no luck.

Comment: Is there a way I can privately send you a console app donwload link which demonstrates the issue? it includes our "test" client id, secret, tenant id etc. a bit sensitive to post publicly

Comment: I have a similar issue, that request (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*) worked well for me and continues working well for the old sites. The recently created sites does not come in the result array. Another interesting thing is if I access via web to an old site, that site stops appearing in the result array. Looks like something is updated and from there it receives the same treatment of the new sites.
Any thoughts about how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an endpoint for Graph API v1.0 named List sites:

```
GET /sites
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http